# Sphinx autodoc also display some imported function

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to document my python program using sphinx and sphinx's autodoc functionality, but I have a problem with one file where I make some import in the form of :

```
from lib import function
```

For some functions (namely asc, and_ and select from SQLAlchemy), sphinx add their doc also in my module documentation. What is surprising is that it's only for these 3. I'm importing in the same module the class SafeConfigParser without trouble, and I have another module  importing functions from the math module without this problem.

For information the .rst file looks like:

```
Mymodule module
=====================
.. automodule:: module
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

Any help is welcome, 
thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.