# How to AutoDoc Document to exclude SQLAlchemy Library DocString from Function DocString?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I tried to generate autodoc string from as a reference document for my project. However, since my source code use import and use SQLAlchemy library, when I issued

> `sphinx-apidoc -f -o docs/source/reference project`

The generated documents not include only the docstring from my functions but also the docstring from SQLAlchemy as well, like so

[image]

Is there anyway I can exclude SQLAlchemy docstring from my function docstring? Thanks

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/24864851/407651 (no answer; could not reproduce).

Comment: If you need help with this, please provide a [mcve].